# how We can count cloud Firestore document of collection, based on document field condition?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to count the document of collection based on fields. I found one reference but giving me error
Property 'select' does not exist on type 'CollectionReference.
Below is my firestore service class code. which I applied to fetch the count.

```
firestore().collection(collectionName).select(documentFieldName).get().then(
(snapshot) => console.log(snapshot.docs.length));
```

Can any one please suggest there is other way to do ?

Now tried with this pic of code

```
  const a = await firestore().collection(collectionName).where('createdBy', 
 CONDITIONS.EQUALS, reportType).get().then(a => (a.size));
```

It giving me as proper response  number but added some string text "Invalid status code" I am not sure why added this string

Invalid status code: 19

Comment: `select` is indeed not a method on Firestore. To query on conditions you'll use `where`. For more on this, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Note that fetching all documents to determine their number is a bad idea in production, so I also recommend reading: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: Thank you !@FrankvanPuffelen using where condition working but as a response giving me  correct count values but    "Invalid status code: 9" but added " Invalid status code" string my code is 

 const a = await firestore().collection(collectionName).where('filedsName', CONDITIONS.EQUALS, reportType).get().then(a => (a.size));

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, but edit your question to show the latest try, and the results you get.

Comment: My bad, now it is working fine. their was some method implementation issue in nodejs side Thank you so much @FrankvanPuffelen